# entity framework property can't be set to string, has to be nullable int

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

> The 'EmpGipNumber' property on 'Employee' could not be set to a 'System.String' value. 
>   You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Int32'.

I'm getting this error, and my Employee Model's EmpGipNumber property is declared like this:

```
public virtual int? EmpGipNumber {get;set;}
```

why is it complaining, its a nullable int already. Ever since I enabled migrations I've been running into a large amount of problems.

The initial migration is empty because I enabled migrations on an existing database. The second migration is this:

```
public override void Up()
        {
            AlterColumn("dbo.Employee", "EmpGipNumber", c => c.Int());
        }
```

it was working fine yesterday. Me going to sleep must've angered it

Comment: Can you show the code of migration? Does this happen during compile\start time of the project o when you try to save the model?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin this is being thrown at the start when I try to get a list of Employees and show the index view

Comment: @Abdul-Ahmad :D Was just trying to not get it closed down for you. Will see if I can role it back.

Comment: @hutchonoid its ok, if it will cause it to get closed then leave it

Comment: What is the stack trace?  what does `c => c.Int()` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more code, I'm wondering if it's a data issue.  In my experience, it will convert any strings that tha can be parsed into ints... have you verified that the data you're converting can be parsed into an int?

Comment: Well there was no data to convert at the time. That column was empty. Another person on the team inserted data into that column after I changed the model and updated the database

Comment: @AbdulAhmad I'm confused by your statement.  Are you saying that it WAS a data issue or not?  I'm assuming not, since you didn't mark the answer.  When you say there was "no data", do you mean that there was a record but no data in the corresponding column?  If that is the case, what was the data in the column?  <null> or empty string? I'm assuming the datastore column type is a char or varchar, correct?

Comment: Yes, there was a column but the values were all 'NULL' I'm not sure what the datastore column type is, I think I saw varchar somewhere though

Comment: You're going to need to know what the database column's datatype is.  If it's a varchar or a char, my understanding is that you'll need to change your Up() method to the following: 

public override void Up()
        {
            AlterColumn("dbo.Employee", "EmpGipNumber", c => c.String());
        }